# Spring Boot application failed to start (Parameter 0 of method ... required a bean of type ... that could not be found)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I would like to set up a starter Spring Boot project like this:

**MyFirstSpringApplication.java:**

```
package com.myfirstspring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyFirstSpringApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyFirstSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java:**

```
package com.myfirstspring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    private SpyGirl spy;
    @Autowired
    public void setSpy(SpyGirl spyFn) {
        this.spy = spyFn;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return this.spy.letsSpeak();
    }
}
```

**SpyGirl.java:**

```
package com.myfirstspring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Scope("session")
public class SpyGirl {
    public String letsSpeak() {
        return "I am the worst spy in the world! (NetBeans)";
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method setSpy in com.myfirstspring.HomeController required a bean of type 'com.myfirstspring.SpyGirl' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myfirstspring.SpyGirl' in your configuration.

2020-05-25 13:39:10.795  WARN 26852 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext
```

If I remove the setter completely with the @Autowired annotation (from HomeController.java) and initialize spy variable as new SpyGirl() it works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only have `@Scope` you also need `@Component` on your `SpyGirl` to make it a spring bean. ]

Comment: still got error: 
```Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-25 14:08:26.427 ERROR 24872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2020-05-25 14:08:26.434  WARN 24872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext```

Comment: Without the proper error (instead of a snippet) we don't know what is wrong. It isn't related to autowiring (assuming you are following the best practices for structuring a Spring Boot application!)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the error message, Spring cannot find a bean of type `SpyGirl`. `@Scope` is not enough to have it seen as a bean. Add `@Component` on your class.

Comment: @M. Deinum was quicker than me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove @Autowired on top of the setSpy method. instead add it to the SpyGirl DI.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SpyGirl spy;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return spy.letsSpeak();
    }
}
```

use annotation like @Component or @Service to the SpyGirl class.

```
@Scope("session")
@Service
public class SpyGirl {
    public String letsSpeak() {
        return "I am the worst spy in the world! (NetBeans)";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use @Autowired annotation, then you don't need setSpy method. remove the method and try.

Comment: try to remove @scope annotation and check whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this in the error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'spyGirl': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;
```

And then I have found a solution in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413290/how-exactly-works-the-spring-session-scope-of-a-bean-what-is-the-default-scope) (special thanks to @DimaSan for it):

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

And also thanks guys (@gervais.b, @M.Deinum, @Natsu D) for the help.